# How to order desc or asc specific column by number

Tags: json, sorting, awk, sed, grep

Want to order columns "usedsize" by number desc or asc.

Input:

```
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"TEMP","size":"1000","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"21","status":0.03},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"DAT","size":"360612","maxsize":"475680","usedsize":"360321","status":75.75},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"CUNBDAT","size":"23800","maxsize":"131072","usedsize":"23694","status":18.08},
```

I try with separator and coulmn row but something seems wrong:

```
sort -t: -k10
```

Expected View:

```
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"DAT","size":"360612","maxsize":"475680","usedsize":"360321","status":75.75},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"CUNBDAT","size":"23800","maxsize":"131072","usedsize":"23694","status":18.08},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"TEMP","size":"1000","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"21","status":0.03},
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the 10th column but the 6th:

```
$ sort -t: -k6 file
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"TEMP","size":"1000","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"21","status":0.03},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"CUNBDAT","size":"23800","maxsize":"131072","usedsize":"23694","status":18.08},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"DAT","size":"360612","maxsize":"475680","usedsize":"360321","status":75.75}
```

Comment: @fedorqui the idea here is to describe and catch column usedsize and after that to sort.

Comment: Mmmm I think I don't understand what you mean. What I am doing with my answer is to sort based on the `21`, `23694`,... values, which happens to be the 6th column based on `:`. Isn't it what you pretend to have?

Answer (score 1):

You could say

```
sort -t, -k5,5r filename
```

If you massage your input a bit to make it valid JSON, you can use perl like this:

```
perl -MJSON -00 -le '
    $data = decode_json(<>);
    print encode_json([sort {$b->{usedsize} <=> $a->{usedsize}} @$data]);
' <<END
[
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"TEMP","size":"1000","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"21","status":0.03},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"DAT","size":"360612","maxsize":"475680","usedsize":"360321","status":75.75},
{"name":"db1","tablespace":"CUNBDAT","size":"23800","maxsize":"131072","usedsize":"23694","status":18.08}
]
END
```

> [{"status":75.75,"name":"db1","usedsize":"360321","maxsize":"475680","size":"360612","tablespace":"DAT"},{"status":18.08,"name":"db1","usedsize":"23694","maxsize":"131072","size":"23800","tablespace":"CUNBDAT"},{"status":0.03,"name":"db1","usedsize":"21","maxsize":"65536","size":"1000","tablespace":"TEMP"}]

Comment: IF add for example:
`{"name":"db2","tablespace":"DAT","size":"3606121","maxsize":"4756801","usedsize":"3603211","status":89.01},`
After that everything sort but is separated because of db2 string how to catch na order then?

Comment: I don't understand: Do you want to sort on `name` first then `usedsize`? Or, do you want all the rows sorted by `usedsize` regardless of `name`?

Comment: I want to sort by "usedsize" but when add previous example or two like them for example:
`{"name":"db2","tablespace":"DAT","size":"3606121","maxsize":"4756801","usedsize‌​":"3603211","status":89.01},
{"name":"db2","tablespace":"EX","size":"3506121","maxsize":"4656801","usedsize‌​":"3503211","status":88.01},`
Everything sort but separate by column "name" just try to see final look is different ...